# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS only one core functioning

Tags: cpu, apic

I have a pc running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with an i7-7700 cpu (4 cores 8 threads) however only obe of the cores is recognised. I have seen this issue in other posts, but I have found no solution as of yet. Here I will place some outputs which I think will be useful for troubleshooting:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x48
cpu MHz     : 1599.890
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
bugs        :
bogomips    : 7199.91
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

lscpu outputs:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1599.890
BogoMIPS:              7199.91
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

From /var/log/kern.log:

```
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.041686] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.041687] CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.041690] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.041690] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.042587] mce: CPU supports 10 MCE banks
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.042599] process: using mwait in idle threads
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.042600] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 64, 2MB 8, 4MB 8
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.042601] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 64, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 4
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.046898] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.052544] ftrace: allocating 32183 entries in 126 pages
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061175] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061177] smpboot: weird, boot CPU (#0) not listed by the BIOS
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061177] smpboot: SMP motherboard not detected
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061178] smpboot: SMP disabled
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061179] Apic disabled
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061179] smpboot: Local APIC not detected. Using dummy APIC emulation.
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061186] Performance Events: PEBS fmt3+, generic architected perfmon, full-width counters, 
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061188] no APIC, boot with the "lapic" boot parameter to force-enable it.
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061188] no hardware sampling interrupt available.
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061189] Intel PMU driver.
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061190] ... version:                4
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061191] ... bit width:              48
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061191] ... generic registers:      4
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061192] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061192] ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061193] ... fixed-purpose events:   3
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061193] ... event mask:             000000070000000f
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061705] x86: Booted up 1 node, 1 CPUs
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061706] smpboot: Total of 1 processors activated (7199.91 BogoMIPS)
Nov 29 12:26:38 jeffers-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [    0.061742] NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
```

Does anyone know what my issue is and how to solve it? I think it's got something to do with APIC and SMP. How do I solve this?

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was the "nolapic" in the kernel boot parameters. Removing this solved the problem.

See how to do this at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters